# Forward find the value without NaN just like Series.asof

Tags: pandas

I have known Series.asof  is `The last row without any NaN is taken`.However i want get `The first row without any NaN is taken`. Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this via:

```
ser[~ser.isnull()].iloc[0]
```

Or

```
ser[ser.isnull().ne(True).idxmax()]
```

Or using the more idiomatic `first_valid_index`:

```
ser[ser.first_valid_index()]
```